# iOS Unable to change X position of label in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

Below a label on the left and a switch on the right appear programmatically in a TableViewCell. I can control the X position of the switch using:

```
switchControl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

But the comparable instruction for the label on the left does nothing, it always stays in the default left hand position.

```
 labelControl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

Do I have to declare the width of the label, whereas with the switch it is known?

```
    lazy var labelControl: UILabel = {
        let labelControl = UILabel()
        labelControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return labelControl
    }()
    
    lazy var switchControl: UISwitch = {
        let switchControl = UISwitch()
        switchControl.isOn = true
        switchControl.onTintColor = UIColor.orange
        switchControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitchAction), for: .valueChanged)
        return switchControl
    }()
    
    
    // MARK: - Init
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(labelControl)
        labelControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        labelControl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        addSubview(switchControl)
        switchControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        switchControl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to add multiple of the same anchor constraints. Presumably, you're getting a auto-layout warnings in the debug console explaining this.

You need to create a constraint that you can then modify:

```
lazy var labelControl: UILabel = {
    let labelControl = UILabel()
    labelControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return labelControl
}()

lazy var switchControl: UISwitch = {
    let switchControl = UISwitch()
    switchControl.isOn = true
    switchControl.onTintColor = UIColor.orange
    switchControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitchAction), for: .valueChanged)
    return switchControl
}()

// add these vars
var labelControlLeftAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
var switchControlRightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

// MARK: - Init

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    addSubview(labelControl)
    labelControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    //labelControl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true

    // create labelControlLeftAnchor
    labelControlLeftAnchor = labelControl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 100)
    labelControlLeftAnchor.isActive = true
    
    addSubview(switchControl)
    switchControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    //switchControl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    // create switchControlRightAnchor
    switchControlRightAnchor = switchControl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -20)
    switchControlRightAnchor.isActive = true
    
}
```

Now, you can change the `.constant` value to "move" the object:

```
// for example
labelControlLeftAnchor.constant = 40
switchControlRightAnchor.constant = -40
```

Comment: Don - I'm sure this is the right approach - many thanks. I am still not able to move the left hand label: The right works perfectly. Will look at it in the morning.

Comment: @EdwardHasted - are you getting auto-layout warning / error messages? As a side note - you should be adding your subviews, and constraining them, to the cell's `contentView` ... not to the cell itself.

Comment: Was working off a tutorial. The text was being presented as: textlabel?.text = sectionType?.description. When I changed it to labelControl.text = sectionType.description the constraints worked. Very many thanks for your help.